# Partially fill color of a shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-core

I have a cup image. Depending on a certain user drag action I would like to fill that cup image with color bottom to top by a percentage of drag operation. Is that possible to do programmatically?

Edit - There's also an alpha channel on the image, a transparent layer around the cup image, which should be omitted while filling the cup shape with color. So only cup gets the color change.

Comment: Quick & dirty: add subview with an overlay image and change it's frame as needed. Good & clean solution will most probably require to use cor e graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to do something like filling up a circle based on user drag actions you can do the following:

1. Get a transparent image of the cup, i.e the portion you want to show filled should be transparent.
2. Create a background uiview behind the cup with 2 subviews, one with the filled color and other with the normal background color.
3. Place the above view below your transparent image of the cup
4. On detecting user drag, just move the normal color uiview upwards to reveal the filled color view, this will give the appearance of getting the cup filled.

I am assuming this logic may give you a start.

Comment: Or, filled region representing the full cup and a a mask that moves with the gestures.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go Praveen. Thanks